# How to fix HTTP 400 Bad Request error when accessing WordPress

Tags: wordpress, apache, google-compute-engine

I am on a WordPress site hosted on Google Compute Engine with an Apache server. The problem I am facing is that when I try to connect to my site using HTTP, I get a 400 Bad Request error. There is no problem with HTTPS, and I have an SSL certificate. When Certbot asked me to, I made sure to redirect HTTP to HTTPS.

I have also made the necessary changes in the files below, but no redirection is done.If you have any leads, I am all ears. Thanks for your help.

here my apache2.conf in etc/apache2/

```html
# This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ for detailed information about
# the directives and /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian about Debian specific
# hints.
#
#
# Summary of how the Apache 2 configuration works in Debian:
# The Apache 2 web server configuration in Debian is quite different to
# upstream's suggested way to configure the web server. This is because Debian's
# default Apache2 installation attempts to make adding and removing modules,
# virtual hosts, and extra configuration directives as flexible as possible, in
# order to make automating the changes and administering the server as easy as
# possible.

# It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
# below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
#
#       /etc/apache2/
#       |-- apache2.conf
#       |       `--  ports.conf
#       |-- mods-enabled
#       |       |-- *.load
#       |       `-- *.conf
#       |-- conf-enabled
#       |       `-- *.conf
#       |       `-- sites-enabled
#       |       `-- *.conf
#
#
# * apache2.conf is the main configuration file (this file). It puts the pieces
#   together by including all remaining configuration files when starting up the
#   web server.
#
# * ports.conf is always included from the main configuration file. It is
#   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections which can be
#   customized anytime.
#
# * Configuration files in the mods-enabled/, conf-enabled/ and sites-enabled/
#   directories contain particular configuration snippets which manage modules,
#   global configuration fragments, or virtual host configurations,
#   respectively.
#
#   They are activated by symlinking available configuration files from their
#   respective *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed by using our
#   helpers a2enmod/a2dismod, a2ensite/a2dissite and a2enconf/a2disconf. See
#   their respective man pages for detailed information.
#
# * The binary is called apache2. Due to the use of environment variables, in
#   the default configuration, apache2 needs to be started/stopped with
#   /etc/init.d/apache2 or apache2ctl. Calling /usr/bin/apache2 directly will not
#   work with the default configuration.


# Global configuration
#
```

here my conf enabled "wordpress-https.conf" in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled

```html
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerAdmin admin@example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  SSLEngine on

  <Directory /var/www/html>
    Options -Indexes
    AllowOverride FileInfo
  </Directory>
    ServerName enerdf.fr
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
ServerAlias www.enerdf.fr
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/enerdf.fr/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/enerdf.fr/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin admin@example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html

  <Directory /var/www/html>
    Options -Indexes
    AllowOverride FileInfo
  </Directory>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =enerdf.fr [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.enerdf.fr
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

I thought about restarting the server after each modification, but it doesn't change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found that I needed to disable ssl on port 80 like this :

```html
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName exemple.com
  SSLEngine off
  Redirect permanent / https://exemple.com
</VirtualHost>
```